# getting value of hash from params

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, hash, parameters

I would like to know the better way to extract hash value from params.
The params looks like below (remember my params name is params[:ad_template]):

```
{"name"=>"name", 
 "description"=>"description", 
 "tag_list"=>"Software Development", 
 "objective"=>"VIDEO_VIEW", 
 "ad_creative_templates_attributes"=>{
   "0"=>{"creative_template_id"=>"2430", "_destroy"=>"false"}
 }, 
 "ad_target_templates_attributes"=>{
   "0"=>{"target_template_id"=>"1526", "_destroy"=>"false"}
 }
}
```

Now i would like to get the value of "creative_template_id" from this params.

I am being able to get this value by executing below code:

```
params[:ad_template][:ad_creative_templates_attributes].first.second[:creative_template_id]
```

Which gives me the value 2430 which is correct but i don't like this approach.
SO i would like to know the better solution to extract that value from the params.

Thanks.

Comment: You can search for specific key's value in deep hash, something like there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15031412/search-for-key-in-a-nested-hash-in-rails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
params[:ad_template][:ad_creative_templates_attributes]['0'][:creative_template_id]
```

Comment: Thanks @Uri Agassi for your solution.I would like to know is it the best solution.