# count elements in an array that is very deeply nested

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I need to figure if there are better ways to count the number of elements in an array that is like 5 levels deep.

I am trying to get a count of number of reports.

Here are my methods:

```
def member_report_sum
  members.sum(&:report_sum)
end

def report_sum
  member.information.groups.sum { |group| group.tasks.reports.count }
end
```

This is my structure:

```
members: [
      {
        id: 'member_id',
        information: {
          groups: [
            {
              name: 'Member1',
              tasks: {
                reports: [
                  {
                    name: 'Report 1',
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              name: 'Member 2',
              tasks: {
                reports: [
                  {
                    name: 'Report2',

                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
```

Is there alternate ways to implement the above?

Comment: That doesn't look like valid data- you have a hash with no keys inside the members array.

Comment: How did you end up with such a structure?

Comment: Looking at your methods it looks like those are active record associations rather than a deeply nested hash. Is that correct?

Comment: actually this response is extracted from an external service.

Comment: This answer looks promising.    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8301566/find-key-value-pairs-deep-inside-a-hash-containing-an-arbitrary-number-of-nested