# How to check if ruby hash member exists recursively?

Tags: ruby, hash, null

This is kinda of confusing.

If you have a hash that contains more hashes that also have hashes and so on, how do you determine if a member exists that is more than one layer deep?

For example:

```
hash 1 =
{
    "layer1" => 
    {
        "layer2" => 
        {
            "layer3" => ['Something', 'Array']
        }
    }
}
```

How would you go about verifying **'Something'** exists in the above hash if the hash only has:

```
hash2 =
{
    "layer1" => 
    {
        "layer2" => ['Other Array']
    }
}
```

For example, I would try to do:

```
if hash2['layer1']['layer2']['layer3'].contains? 'Something'
  puts "Found Something!"
end
```

But this would error **undefined method `contains?' for nil:NilClass**. Where layer3 would be the NilClass because it doesn't exist. It would suffice if one of these embedded hashses was Nil then say it doesn't exist, but you can't easily test for their existence because that also will return Nil if you are a layer too deep. Is there a function in ruby that checks each top level layer for Nil recursively instead of the specific member you request when you would call .nil? **E.g. What I would think would work!**

```
if hash2['layer1']['layer2']['layer3'].nil?
  puts 'layer3 exists'
end
```

But .nil? **only** checks if 'layer3' exists. IS there a method that starts at 'layer1' then checks if 'layer2' exists then 'layer3' and so forth. And at any of the parts are nil it returns false? Because if 'layer2' or 'layer1' didn't exist it would error out saying undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8301566/5101493 may help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out [`Hash#dig()`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0_preview1/Hash.html#method-i-dig).  It takes an array of keys and looks them up recursively, returning `nil` if any of them are missing.  From the docs:

```
h = { foo: {bar: {baz: 1}}}

h.dig(:foo, :bar, :baz)           #=> 1
h.dig(:foo, :zot)                 #=> nil
```

Just note that if `baz` was `nil`, that first `dig` call would have returned `nil`.  So it's only a replacement for checking if a nested key exists if you know you won't have `nil`s stored in your hash.

Comment: `.dig`  is awesome! Also keep in mind it only works in versions 2.3+. If this is going inside a gem or some other library it will not work for users in previous versions.

Comment: Omg, this is exactly what I was looking for. It is hard to look up the solution for this because the way of phrasing this problem can lead to so many different versions.

Answer (score 0):

Not the best solution, but I wrote this:

```
h = {"layer1"=>
       {"layer2"=>
          {"layer3"=>["Something", "Array"]}
       },
     "layerx" => ["d"],
     "layerz" => {"layera" => "deep"}
}

def vals(h)
  return h if !h.is_a?(Hash)
  h.values.map(&method(:vals)).flatten
end
vals(h) #=> ["Something", "Array", "d", "deep"]
```

`vals` gives the values nested deep inside hash-es. You can check if your element is there in that.