# Collect specific values from an array of hashes

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I have this complex hash called data in a JSON file, just below. 
I am interested in the field "videoId"

so i ran this code :

```
puts data["videoId"]
```

But i get no results. What would be the best way to get all the videosid in ruby ? and why code is not working ?

```
{
    "etag": "\"DuHzAJ-eQIiCIp7p4ldoVcVAOeY/2rushbFMdJCgH0PsUecXvdIjrIA\"",
    "items": [
        {
            "etag": "\"DuHzAJ-eQIiCIp7p4ldoVcVAOeY/SGIvedEKHZeJcInXZg-T4Lde7gE\"",
            "id": "TExreW5lbzZYQXYxbm8xakgzM0syQm1nLnhTWTc1cUpfa0lr",
            "kind": "youtube#playlistItem",
            "snippet": {

                "publishedAt": "2018-05-21T16:00:00.000+00:00",
                "resourceId": {
                    "kind": "youtube#video",
                    "videoId": "xSY75qJ_kIk"
                },

                "title": "The Key (Wax Trax Mix) - Space Bunny | Surreal [1998]"
            }
        },
        {
            "etag": "\"DuHzAJ-eQIiCIp7p4ldoVcVAOeY/Z7hQMBr8AzIyI7n2LPBnd7AUwjs\"",
            "id": "TExreW5lbzZYQXYxbm8xakgzM0syQm1nLmVISWd4c2EzckVz",
            "kind": "youtube#playlistItem",
            "snippet": {

                "publishedAt": "2018-05-18T08:00:00.000+00:00",
                "resourceId": {
                    "kind": "youtube#video",
                    "videoId": "eHIgxsa3rEs"

                    }
                },
                "title": "Coin coin Pata'tribe mix [Old School Tekno Tribe]"
            }
        },
        {
            "etag": "\"DuHzAJ-eQIiCIp7p4ldoVcVAOeY/T2xQFVjUHZYJ2FHGa4Yb82yMubc\"",
            "id": "TExreW5lbzZYQXYxbm8xakgzM0syQm1nLmgxMFlVSVVxb1lN",
            "kind": "youtube#playlistItem",
            "snippet": {

                "publishedAt": "2018-05-17T16:00:00.000+00:00",
                "resourceId": {
                    "kind": "youtube#video",
                    "videoId": "h10YUIUqoYM"
                },

                "title": "Lil Louis 1992.09.25 @ Hacienda"
            }
        },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Hash is a dictionary-like collection of unique keys and their values. Also called associative arrays, they are similar to Arrays, but where an Array uses integers as its index, a Hash allows you to use any object type.

Of course, a value can be any object - string, method, nil, number, object. So, only after create, we can know that is saved in our hash. For this reason when trying to get all key:

```
data.keys # => ["etag", "items"]
```

There is no any nested key. So finding value by missing key return `nil`.

To select all videoId you must do something like this:

```
data["items"].map { |item| item["snippet"]["resourceId"]["videoId"] }.compact
```

Also, you can update Hash class as [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8301566/find-key-value-pairs-deep-inside-a-hash-containing-an-arbitrary-number-of-nested):

```
class Hash
  def deep_find(key, object=self, found=nil)
    if object.respond_to?(:key?) && object.key?(key)
      return object[key]
    elsif object.is_a? Enumerable
      object.find { |*a| found = deep_find(key, a.last) }
      return found
    end
  end
end
```

And then run

```
data["items"].map { |item| item.deep_find('videoId') }
```

That method avoids the error when the json will have a variable structure.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an array, this is a hash. To get all `videoId`s, one might [`Enumerable#map`] `items` array to dig the values:

```
data["items"].map { |item| item["snippet"]["resourceId"]["videoId"] }
```

resulting in the array of `videoId`s.

---

Alternatively, one might use [`Iteraptor`](https://github.com/am-kantox/iteraptor) gem to just grep for the `videoId`s:

```
data.segar(/videoId/) { |*args| puts args.inspect }
```

Comment: thank you very much ! Yes you're right it is an hash, :).

Comment: Your other way is also very nice, thanks for sharing the Iteraptor gem

Comment: If I was to thank myself, I’d thank for _writing_ this gem in the first place.