# How do I see if a multi-dimensional hash has a value in ruby?

Tags: ruby, hash

Currently I am doing the following, but I am sure there must be a better way:

```
def birthday_defined?(map)
    map && map[:extra] && map[:extra][:raw_info] && map[:extra][:raw_info][:birthday]
end
```

There may be cases where only `map[:extra]` is defined, and then I will end up getting Nil exception errors cause `map[:extra][:raw_info]` doesn't exist if I dont use my checked code above.

Comment: If `map[:extra][:raw_info][:birthday]` is defined then `map[:extra]` must also be defined.

Comment: @AustinHenley But if you only test for `map[:extra][:raw_info][:birthday]` and it doesn't exist, you get a `NoMethodError` for `NilClass`.... hence the long expression (I'm guessing)

Comment: duplicate of [Is there a clean way to avoid calling a method on nil in a nested params hash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5429790/is-there-a-clean-way-to-avoid-calling-a-method-on-nil-in-a-nested-params-hash) (and many others)

Comment: To me, this is a sign that your data is structured incorrectly. We can propose a million ways of "hiding" this complexity, but the method probably just shouldn't need to dig through three hash levels in the first place.

Comment: @pje Unless the hash is coming from an outside API like Facebook (as this one appears to be) and hence such complexity can't be avoided.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid NoMethodError for missing elements in nested hashes, without repeated nil checks?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4371716/how-to-avoid-nomethoderror-for-missing-elements-in-nested-hashes-without-repeat)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Rails, then you can use [`try`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-try) (and [`NilClass#try`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/NilClass.html#method-i-try)):

```
value = map.try(:[], :extra).try(:[], :raw_info).try(:[], :birthday)
```

That looks a bit repetitive: it is just doing the same thing over and over again while feeding the result of one step into the next step. That code pattern means that we have a hidden injection:

```
value = [:extra, :raw_info, :birthday].inject(map) { |h, k| h.try(:[], k) }
```

This approach nicely generalizes to any path into `map` that you have in mind:

```
path  = [ :some, :path, :of, :keys, :we, :care, :about ]
value = path.inject(map) { |h, k| h.try(:[], k) }
```

Then you can look at `value.nil?`.

Of course, if you're not using Rails then you'll need a replacement for `try` but that's not difficult.

Answer (score 1):

I have two ways. Both have the same code but subtly different:

```
# Method 1

def birthday_defined?(map)     
    map[:extra][:raw_info][:birthday] rescue nil # rescues current line
end

# Method 2

def birthday_defined?(map)     
    map[:extra][:raw_info][:birthday]
rescue # rescues whole method
    nil
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a begin/rescue block.

```
begin
  map[:extra][:raw_info][:birthday]
rescue Exception => e
  'No birthday! =('
end
```

Comment: -1 for using exceptions for control flow and for over-rescuing. Don't ever rescue Exception: http://www.mikeperham.com/2012/03/03/the-perils-of-rescue-exception/

Comment: It works, so i don't know why the downvote. There are many ways to solving the problem, and this is one of them.

Answer (score 0):

That's idiomatic why to do it. And yes it can be a little cumbersome.

If you want to extend `Hash` a bit though, you can do some cool stuff with something like a key path. See [Access Ruby Hash Using Dotted Path Key String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7139471/transform-a-ruby-hash-into-a-dotted-path-key-string)

```
def birthday_defined?
  map.dig('extra.raw_info.birthday')
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a little hacky but it will work:

```
def birthday_defined?(map)
    map.to_s[":birthday"]
end
```

If `map` contains `:birthday` then it will return the string which will evaluate to `true` in a conditional statement while if it doesn't contain `:birthday`, it will return `nil`.

**Note:** This assumes the key `:birthday` does not appear at potentially multiple locations in `map`.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
def birthday_defined?(map)
  map
  .tap{|x| (x[:extra] if x)
  .tap{|x| (x[:raw_info] if x)
  .tap{|x| (x[:birthday] if x)
  .tap{|x| return x}}}}
end
```